# BPS V3 Minecraft character rig animation problem (snapping)

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create a Minecraft animation with the BPS V3 rig.[image]

When i add keyframes, and play, instead of the character gradually moving to a position, it snaps into position as soon as the play cursor (i think that's what it's called?) reaches the keyframe. This is a MAJOR setback as i can't animate. pls help!! ＞﹏＜

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting the first keyframe, then pressing <kbd>T</kbd> to change the keyframe interpolation. In the menu that pops up, select anything other than *Constant.* *Constant interpolation* causes the keyframe's value to be held constant until the next keyframe.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I set it to Bezier and it worked. Is there a way to set it so new keyframes will be Bezier?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.